# c# Dropbox RestSharp download file to stream

Tags: c#, dropbox, dropbox-api, restsharp

I have an 'ASP.NET' console application and I use 'RestSharp' client for Dropbox.

I use this code to download a file :

```
 var baseUrl = "https://content.dropboxapi.com";

 var client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
 client.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForRequestToken(mc_apiKey, mc_appsecret);

 RestRequest request = new RestRequest(string.Format("/{0}/files/auto", mc_version), Method.GET);

 client.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(mc_apiKey, mc_appsecret, accessToken.Token, accessToken.Secret);
 request.AddParameter("path", path);

 var responseAccount = client.Execute(request);
 var fileString = responseAccount.Content;
 byte[] b1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (fileString);
```

When call `client.Execute(request)`the whole file is loaded in memory, so when I have a very largefile in Dropbox the program will crash.

I need to get the file to stream without using `client.DownloadData(request).SaveAs(path)` to download to local storage.

I need to be able to stream the file in chunks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the best answer in [link](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2012/07/using-oauth-1-0-with-the-plaintext-signature-method/):

```
 string url = String.Format("https://content.dropboxapi.com/1/files/auto{0}?oauth_consumer_key={1}&oauth_token={2}&oauth_signature={3}%26{4}", path, app-key, access-token, app-secret, access-token-secret);
 HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
 webRequest.Method = "Get";
 WebResponse webResponse = null;
  try
  {
     webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
     return webResponse.GetResponseStream();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw ex;       
  }
```

Comment: Well, this answer uses another approach for making HTTP request - not RestSharp as stated in question caption and tag. This is not direct answer on the question. Just a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the request.ResponseWriter like so :

```
  var baseUrl = "https://content.dropboxapi.com";

  var client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
  client.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForRequestToken(mc_apiKey,mc_appsecret);

  RestRequest request = new RestRequest(string.Format("/{0}/files/auto", mc_version), Method.GET);

  client.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(mc_apiKey, mc_appsecret, accessToken.Token, accessToken.Secret);
  request.AddParameter("path", path);

  string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
  using(var stream = File.Create(tempFile, 1024, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose ))
  {
    request.ResponseWriter = (responseStream) => responseStream.CopyTo(stream);
    var response = client.DownloadData(request);
  }
```

You can see the example from the docs [here](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Other-Usage-Examples)

Comment: Thanks @swestner for reply.but i need to get stream not save the file in temp.this will add more size to my disk.if i will download for example 10 TB from dropbox my service will crash.

Comment: If you are downloading 10 gigs its going to end up on your disk regardless, whether it is in a specified location, or in the pagefile.sys the system uses.  That being said, the response writer can be any stream, if you prefer I could provide an example with a different with whatever stream you prefer

Comment: i used this code `using (var stream = new MemoryStream())` but still read all data to the memory

I used the header `request.AddHeader("Range", "bytes=0-8388607");` to get part of the file and work perfect.

Comment: @swestner that example would come in handy as I am looking to download a simple pdf but all i get is a null from the response stream.