# Cannot download a pdf with RestSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, download, restsharp

I have been struggling to download a simple pdf hosted online using restsharp. I have been playing around with the code for over an hour and all I get are null object results.

The file downloads easily in POSTMAN using a GET and no content header set but still what gives?

Below is the noddy sandbox test I have been experimenting around with:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Sandbox
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var uri = "https://www.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/2018/download/2018NewMeShHeadings.pdf";
        var client = new RestClient();
        var request = new RestRequest(uri, Method.GET);
        //request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        byte[] response = client.DownloadData(request);
        File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\temp\1.pdf", response);
    }
}
```

**Update**: *[Return a Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34183238/c-sharp-dropbox-restsharp-download-file-to-stream)*

```
        var baseUri = "https://www.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/2018/download/";
        var client = new RestClient(baseUri);
        var request = new RestRequest("2018NewMeShHeadings.pdf", Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
        var stream = File.Create(tempFile, 1024, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);
        request.ResponseWriter = responseStream => responseStream.CopyTo(stream);
        var response = client.DownloadData(request);
```

The stream is now populated with the downloaded data.

Comment: Any one who lands here wanting to return the stream via WebApi - then see here: http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2017/02/downloading-an-inmemory-file-using-web-api-2/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
    var uri = "https://www.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/2018/download/";
    var client = new RestClient(uri);
    var request = new RestRequest("2018NewMeShHeadings.pdf", Method.GET);
    //request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    byte[] response = client.DownloadData(request);
```

Comment: this worked - is there any need or advantage in adding the header then?

Comment: how do you return a response stream? I am getting nulls again.

Comment: Return where? What do you mean by "nulls again"? You said it worked. What changed?

Comment: You either use DowloadData or use stream.

Comment: I have updated my answer above - it now incorporates a stream to be returned from an API call (WebApi). Would you just return the byte[] back from DownloadData or return the stream as shown in the update code above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158342/discussion-between-ibrarmumtaz-and-yuri-s).

Comment: Was stuck trying to use `client.ExecuteAsync` for the same type of scenario (downloading a file) and switched to the `client.DownloadData` method and it fixed my issues.  Thanks!